# Is there a way to scale variables with MinMax Scaling in Python to avoid the extreme values of 0 and 1?

Tags: python, psychopy, economics, minmax

I'm working with psychometric data and am using the following scaling function at the moment:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler 
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
score= scaler.fit_transform(df['raw_score'])*10
```

I intend to use this in a survey to return scores to people out of 10, and am trying to avoid the extreme score of 0 or 10 for outliers/ people having the minimum or the maximum score.

For example, instead of the score 10, I would prefer if the score was 9.8 since viewing a score as 10 can be uncomfortable from a visual perspective. I understand that this entails including a level of error in the scoring, but I don't think that would be an issue of the scores being returned are not too far off from the original.

I tried using the following code to increase the max/ decrease the min by 1% to adjust the scores:

```
def rescale(score, minimum, maximum):
    if type(score) == pd.Series:
        score = score[0]
    else:
        score = score
        
    if score >= maximum:
        maximum = 1.1* score

    if score <= minimum:
        minimum = 0.9* score

    return ((score - minimum)/(maximum - minimum)) * 10
```

I was wondering if there was a standard method of excluding extremes in python?

Comment: What about just multiplying the score by `0.96` and then adding `0.2`? That transforms `0` to `0.2`, `10` to `9.8`, but keeps the middle point of `5.0` at `5.0`. And you can easily undo the process for any value.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is called CLAMP; consider the `clip()` method from numpy

```
import numpy as np  
np.clip([0,2.35,6.4,8.0,8.9,9.999,10.0,10,10.1], 0.2, 9.8)
```